# Using Launchd to invoke a Python script?

Tags: macos, python, launchd

As a continuation from my initial question...

[Routinely backup log file in OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/294377/routinely-backup-log-file-in-osx)

I'm attempting to backup a logfile on an OSX computer and a jailbroken iPhone. LaunchD was recommended as a solution and some Google searches later revealed LingOn to be the tool to use.

The output (after me filling the fields) gives me this PList:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.ash.MySuperLaunchd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>python</string>
        <string>/Users/ash/Desktop/sendemail.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>3600</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now running my python script by invoking it in the terminal will successfully send the email to my inbox with the attachments I need.

LaunchD just doesn't launch though and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Have you registered your plist with launchctl? Where did you put this file?

Comment: Lingon puts the plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons/

Comment: I also registered with `sudo launchctl load w- com.ash.MySuperLaunchd`

Comment: I thin you need to load the file path, not the arbitrary identifier you assign, at least the man page looks like that. Also, I recommend you make the script file executable, add a shebang header specifying the path to `which python` and execute it directly to circumvent PATH issues. Lastly, check `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app` for error messages.

Comment: I double checked the shebang header and it was not pointing to the right directory. My fault as I copy and pasted a script that was made for Linux. Everything is now working, only I do not know how to replicate this on the iPhone.

Comment: We consider iPhone off topic in this community. I'll flag your post for migration to Apple.StackExchange.com where I *think* you'll have a better chance.

Comment: `which python` might give you the path to python; alternatively use `/usr/bin/env python`. Both work on OS X, I know nothing about jailbroken iPhone scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the agent. Either relogin, or `launchctl load /path/to/file.plist`.

`RunAtLoad` is false by default, so the script is run for the first time `StartInterval` seconds after it's loaded, in this case 3600.

The path in `ProgramArguments` needs to point to the permanent location of the script, so it probably shouldn't be at `~/Desktop/`. The target script doesn't need to be executable. But as correctly troubleshot by @DanielBeck in the comments, check that you're able to for example `python /Users/ash/Desktop/sendemail.py` in the first place and that the shebang line is correct.