# Is there a way to run a .Net application as a background app/service on Mac?

Tags: macos

I'm working in .Net 5 which supports Mac; so far my applications I create are launched `dotnet <myapplication>` from the command-line.

I have written one I would like to run continuously in the background a bit like a Windows service, or at least without a visible window. Ideally it would restart if it terminates, etc.

Is this feasible, and if so how might I achieve it?

Comment: Sorry, that was a language misunderstanding because the system used to run services on macos is called `launchd` and I thought your "launched" was just launchd with a typo. See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/305345/62676) how to create such a script. If is for python but using dotnet or python should not make much of a difference. But I would use the full path to `dotnet` executable.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot more sense :)